# One column referencing two different tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, users and organizations.

I am about to create a new table "actions", the action can be perform on a user or an organization.

How to model this table?

One option is to have a type column along with two columns for each of the tables' id.

type | user_id | org_id

But this will stay sparse.

Another option is to have type and a generic entity id

type | entity_id

In the second approach, how should I configure my foreign key constraints?

This is what I have tried and I am getting an error with two foreign keys:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE organizations (org_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE actions (
    action_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    entity_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES organizations (org_id)
  );

INSERT INTO users DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO users DEFAULT VALUES;

INSERT INTO organizations DEFAULT VALUES;

INSERT INTO actions (type, entity_id) VALUES ('user', 2);
```

Error:

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO actions (type, entity_id) VALUES ('user', 2);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "actions" violates foreign key constraint "actions_entity_id_fkey1"
DETAIL:  Key (entity_id)=(2) is not present in table "organizations".
```

Comment: Like it or not, you have described two foreign key constraints. I would recommend you implement that requirement as two foreign keys columns.

Comment: Are those actors inclusive, exclusive, or entirely optional?

Comment: They are exclusive, each action should have exactly one actor @TheImpaler

Comment: Is it possible that, down the line, you might need to perform an action on some level between user and organization (e.g. a group of users within an organization)? If that's a possibility, you might want to rethink your users/organizations table to be hierarchical. That way, you could have an `entities` table, and your `actions` table would apply to that table with just a standard foreign key constraint.

Comment: @Zack No, that doesn't look like something I may need in the near future.

Comment: if each action can have only one actor, and that actor may be an org or user id, then an approach might be that you have a bit that you flip from user to org as needed.

table
action
entity_type "user|org"
entity_id

Comment: @TheImpaler I get the following error with that:

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO actions (type, entity_id) VALUES ('user', 2);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "actions" violates foreign key constraint "actions_entity_id_fkey1"
DETAIL:  Key (entity_id)=(2) is not present in table "organizations".

```
I am not sure if I am setting my FK constraint correctly. Adding the queries to the question.

Comment: By creating a "type" column, which is varchar, you waste a lot of storage space and memory, much more than if you have a column for each entity. `CREATE TABLE actions ( action_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, userid int references users, orgid int references organizations );` You can add a unique index per column if there should only be one action per user/organization. There is no need to store what type it is: just check which column has a value.
`

Comment: If you still want it in the same column, then you have to drop the foregin key requirement: it can never be true for both tables at the same time. In that case, I recommend that type is an int (or shortint) instead of varchar: It takes up less space, and is faster to handle.

Comment: @some Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I guess I'll go ahead with having two columns in the actions table: user_id and org_id and each can have its own FK + I can add a check on user_id and org_id so that exactly one is always set to null, and there is no need to save another column for the type as it can easily be derived from the presence of the values. I guess this makes the most sense as the database is aware of all the constraints and relationships now, and there is no extra context needed from the application side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a "type" column, which is varchar, you waste a lot of storage space and memory, much more than if you have a column for each entity.

If you still want it in the same column, then you have to drop the foreign key requirement: it can never be true for both tables at the same time.

Here is my suggestion:

```
CREATE TABLE users (user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE organizations (org_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE actions (
  action_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int REFERENCES users,
  org_id int REFERENCES organizations,
  CHECK (
   (
     (user_id IS NOT NULL)::int +
     (org_id IS NOT NULL)::int
   ) = 1
);

-- insert test data to have different id
INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES (42);
ISNERT INTO organizations (org_id) VALUES (32);

-- working (as expected)
INSERT INTO actions (user_id) VALUES (42);
INSERT INTO actions (org_id) VALUES (32);
INSERT INTO actions (user_id, org_id) VALUES (42, NULL);
INSERT INTO actions (user_id, org_id) VALUES (NULL, 32);

-- not working (as expected)
INSERT INTO actions (user_id, org_id) VALUES (42, 32);
INSERT INTO actions (user_id, org_id) VALUES (NULL, NULL);
```

I added table check constraint to verify that only one of user_id or org_id is set.

You can add a unique index per column if there should only be one action per user/organization. There is no need to store what type it is: just check which column has a value.

**Update**

Changed the check constraint after suggestion by [JohnH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20151367/):
"*An advantage of this approach is that the list of mutually exclusive items can be extended by adding additional `+ (item IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER` expressions. Another advantage is that each item only appears once in the check constraint*"

Comment: A better check constraint would be `CHECK (((user_id IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER + (org_id IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER) = 1`. An advantage of this approach is that the list of mutually exclusive items can be extended by adding additional `+ (item IS NOT NULL)::INTEGER` expressions. Another advantage is that each item only appears once in the check constraint.

Comment: @JohnH I agree. With COALESCE in mind I was searching for a function that returns number of not null arguments, but couldn't find it. Casing boolean to int didn't cross my mind.